# Create fake data for rest mapper running in Kubernetes

Tags: azure, go, kubernetes

I can run the following code when providing a kubeconfig. Doing so I was able to get the value of `gr`:

```
func (o *ApplyOptions) RestMapper() (meta.RESTMapper, error) {
    gr, err := restmapper.GetAPIGroupResources(o.discoveryClient)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    mapper := restmapper.NewDiscoveryRESTMapper(gr)
    return mapper, nil
}
```

Then I have initiated the following code:

```
var kubeconfig *string

kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", filepath.Join(home, ".kube", "config"), "(optional) absolute path to the kubeconfig file")

flag.Parse()

// use the current context in kubeconfig
config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

dynamicClient, err := dynamic.NewForConfig(config)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
discoveryClient, err := discovery.NewDiscoveryClientForConfig(config)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

applyOptions := apply.NewApplyOptions(dynamicClient, discoveryClient)
if err := applyOptions.Apply(context.Background(), []byte(applyStr)); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("apply error: %v", err)
}
```

Now I use it **for unit test** and `gr` is empty (from `restmapper.GetAPIGroupResources(o.discoveryClient)`) above when debug it,
, how can I add some fake to make it works also from the test ?

```
var _ = DescribeTable(“test”, func(applyOptions *ApplyOptions, filename string, isExpectedErr bool, expectedErrMsg string) {


    applyOptions = ApplyOptions{
        discoveryClient: clientset.Discovery() ,
        //discoveryClient: &k8sfake.Clientset,
        dynamicClient:   dynamicfake.NewSimpleDynamicClient(runtime.NewScheme()),

    }

   // Here I need to initiate some fake data
    restmapper, err := applyOptions.RestMapper()
    if err != nil {
        Fail(err.Error())
    }
```

The error which I get is `"k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/**meta.NoKindMatchError**"`

**Update**

To make it clear:
I am trying to create a unit test for [this function](https://github.com/pytimer/k8sutil/blob/main/apply/apply.go#L119) with `kind: deployment` and I got the above error.

Comment: what `applyOptions.RestMapper()` from `DescribeTable` callable gives you ?

Answer (score -1):

One possible approach is to abstract the `restmapper` away, this will make `ApplyOptions` to rely on abstractions, thus you can mock it. Assuming you are unit testing.

We can call it `RESTMapperDiscovery` this type will encapsulate the `restmapper` capabilities used by `ApplyOptions`. It is basically a wrapper.

```
type RESTMapperDiscovery struct {}
func (RESTMapperDiscovery) FromGroupResources(cl discovery.DiscoveryInterface) (meta.RESTMapper, error)
```

`FromGroupResources` will concretely implement the code currently part of `func (o *ApplyOptions) RestMapper()`.

To achieve polymorphism we just need an interface.

```
type DiscoveryRESTMapper interface {
    FromGroupResources(cl discovery.DiscoveryInterface) (meta.RESTMapper, error)
}
```

At this stage `ApplyOptions` will also depend on `DiscoveryRESTMapper`.

```
type ApplyOptions struct {
    //... other fields
    restMapper DiscoveryRESTMapper
}
func (o *ApplyOptions) RestMapper() (meta.RESTMapper, error) {
    return o.restMapper.FromGroupResources(o.discoveryClient)
}
```

When testing, you can use a type which fulfils that interface and will return some fake data. `meta.RESTMapper` is an interface as well, thereof your fake data has to implement.

```
type mockRESTMapper struct {}
func (mockRESTMapper) FromGroupResources(cl discovery.DiscoveryInterface) (meta.RESTMapper, error) {
    // return the fake meta.RESTMapper
}

applyOptions = &ApplyOptions{
    discoveryClient: clientset.Discovery() ,
    dynamicClient:   dynamicfake.NewSimpleDynamicClient(runtime.NewScheme()),
    restMapper: mockRESTMapper{},

}

// here you have the fake data
restmapper, err := applyOptions.RestMapper()
if err != nil {
    Fail(err.Error())
}
```

This approach relies on composition and interfaces to decouple external dependencies. k8s apis as `restmapper` seems to rely on the same mechanism, thus you could also mock all that from the currently dependencies of `ApplyOptions`. The trade-off here is your solution being tightly coupled with k8s api, this could result in break changes with `restmapper` versions and/or maintenance burden.

Comment: i am also facing the above problem,but my problem isnt resolve with this method

Comment: I try it and it doesnt works for me, maybe I miss something, it will  be great if you can provide a test for this https://github.com/pytimer/k8sutil/blob/main/apply/apply.go#L119